# Why doesn't "EOT" end the message body and send the message when using "mailx"?

Tags: mailx

This is what I tried:

```bash
$ mailx -s "test email" cloud
Cc: 
"again and agina"
.
EOT
```

Or,

```bash
$ mailx -s "test email" cloud
Cc: 
"this is the first email"
<< EOT
```

But after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> nothing happens.
Why?

Comment: Why should `EOT` be recognized as the end of input? Try `mailx -s "test email" cloud
<< EOT` to recognize the end of the heredoc.

Comment: @doneal24 The same issue again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing magical about the thee-letter-string `EOT`. You have probably seen it used as a delimiter in here-document redirections in shell scripts from time to time. Almost any word may be used as a delimiter for a here-document redirection, although it's customary to use a short-ish descriptive word written in all upper-case letters; so you could, for example, send a message with `mailx` by giving the utility the message on its standard input stream like so:

```bash
mailx -s 'test message' myself <<'END_MESSAGE'
This is the message.
Possibly on many lines.
END_MESSAGE
```

This would use `mailx` non-interactively to send an email consisting of two lines of text to the user `myself`. The body of the message is *quoted*, i.e., the shell won't try to expand variables etc., in it, due to the quoting of the initial delimiter (`'END_MESSAGE'`).

However, from seeing the two commands in the question, you appear to want to use `mailx` interactively to type a message into the utility.

If you have had the `dot` option set in your `~/.mailrc` file (`set dot`), then typing a single dot on a line by itself *as you did in the first part of your question* would end the message body and cause the email to be sent:

```bash
$ cat ~/.mailrc
set dot
```

```bash
$ mailx -s 'test message' myself
Cc:
This is the message.
Possibly on many lines.
.
```

Typing the lone dot and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> causes the message to be sent.

If you don't have the `dot` option set or if you have the `nodot` option set in `~/.mailrc`, the message body is instead ended using <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on an otherwise empty line.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> sends (commits, submits) the current line to the program waiting for input, and if the current line is *empty*, this will signal the end of input. This is true not just for `mailx` but for most programs reading interactive input from their standard input stream.

Using `.` on an empty line is also how you signal the end of user input in the `ed` editor when finishing entering text after issuing the `i`, `a`, or `c` command to insert, append or change the text in the current editing buffer. It wouldn't surprise me if `mailx` inherited this custom from `ed`.

Answer (score 2):

As my unprivileged user I typed:

```
$ mailx -s "test email" root <<EOTx
> "this is the first email"
> EOTx
$
```

and a little while later:

```
Return-Path: <XXXXXX@XXXXXX.home>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@XXXXXX.home
Received: by XXXXXX.home (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id ADEF4C0CF994; Sat, 27 Aug 2022 20:32:56 +0100 (BST)
Date: Sat, 27 Aug 2022 20:32:56 +0100
To: root@XXXXXX.home
Subject: test email
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Message-Id: <20220827193256.ADEF4C0CF994@XXXXXX.home>
From: XXXXXX <XXXXXX@XXXXXX.home>
X-Evolution-Source: mbox:/var/spool/mail/XXXXXX

"this is the first email"
```

root's mail is directed to my unprivileged account.

Doneal's comment is accurate as far as it goes, however your final line of `<< EOT` is the error in that case.  It should have been `EOT` without the redirection.

Comment: Note that the three letters `EOT` are not special in any way other than that the "heredoc" is introduced and terminated with them. You could have more easily avoided the whole thing and used Ctrl/D to terminate `mailx` reading from _stdin_ (the keyboard)

Comment: Re. the last part, note that inserting a final line `EOF` wouldn't have helped them, since they didn't have the here-doc redirection in the command (despite a comment telling them to do that)

Comment: "@doneal24 The same issue again", so it appears that they did try Doneal's first line.

Comment: I'm noting that the user is using `mailx` interactively in the question and that using a here-document would instead use the utility non-interactively (it would no longer prompt for the "carbon-copy" recipient list, for example, and variables etc. will be expanded by the shell if you don't quote the here-document). It may _possibly_ be worth mentioning this. I don't know if it makes any difference whatsoever to the user.

Comment: @Martin, perhaps they did try, but they're still missing the actual redirection. The comment suggests using `mailx -s "test email" cloud << EOT`, but the command they've added in the question is still `mailx -s "test email" cloud`.

Comment: @ilkkach.  The OP first gave the two examples.  Then Doneal24 suggested putting the redirection in the right place.  After which the OP replied to Doneal that it didn't work but didn't further edit the question.  Hence I credited Doneal's response and moved from **that** position.  Because you appeared confused I edited the sentence to clarify "**in that case**" for you.

Comment: @Martin, the [initial revision](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/715130/revisions) (hover over the timestamps to see that actual times) of the question is timestamped 16:59, it only contained one example. doneal24's comment is timestamped 17:29, and the edit to the question that added the second example is timestamped 17:54 (and the reply comment at 17:53). Based on the timeline, it still seems to me that the edit was made in response to the suggestion in the comment. But the suggestion was implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Regardless, just changing the `<< EOT` to `EOT` in the second example in the question wouldn't help, as one would also have to add the here-doc redirection on the command line; it was missing from the sample run in the question. You added it here of course, but that statement in the last paragraph of this answer appears to ignore the other part of problem the attempt in the question had.